# Projective closure of zero set of polynomial equals the zero set of the homogenized polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm having trouble figuring out why this is the case:

If $f\in K[X_1,...,X_n]$, $V(f)$ is the zero set of $f$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $V(f^*)$ is the zero set in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of the homogenization $f^*$ of $f$, then $V(f^*)=(V(f))^*$, the algebraic closure of $(V(f))^*$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

(alternative definition for $(V(f))^*$: Let $I^*$ be the ideal of $K[X_1,...,X_{n+1}]$ generated by the set $\{f^*:f\in I(V(f))\}$, and define $(V(f))^*=V_P(I^*)$, the zero set of $I^*$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$.)

Comment: So you're using that $V(f) = \{ (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in K^n \mid f(a_1, \dots, a_n) = 0 \}$? In that case, what is $(V(f))^*$? The star you defined in your post is only for polynomials.

Comment: That's right. I've just added the definition of $(V(F))^*$ :)